# Question mark DQL is not considered?

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, dql

I have the following DQL query:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('p.genre')
                ->from('Profile p')
                ->where('sf_guard_user_id = ?',  11);
```

If I return the SQL syntax with `$sql = $query->getSqlQuery();` I get:

```
SELECT p.id AS p__id, p.genre AS p__genre FROM profile p WHERE (p.sf_guard_user_id = ?)
```

This is not normal. It should be **11** not **?**:

```
SELECT p.id AS p__id, p.genre AS p__genre FROM profile p WHERE (p.sf_guard_user_id = 11)
```

And if I write:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('p.genre')
                ->from('Profile p')
                ->where('sf_guard_user_id = ' .  11);
```

The SQL syntax is correct.

Normally DQL should do this automatically. Why isn't happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how prepared statement works. Values will be bound on database server Hence doctrine can not show the real values with the query.

Doctrine will show a question mark if you use prepared statement not the real value.

Checkout how it is describing [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/ru/dql-doctrine-query-language)

Comment: Actually I use like that: `$ID = 11; $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('p.genre')
                ->from('Profile p')
                ->where('sf_guard_user_id = ? ' ,  $ID);` But the resut is the same error (is displaying the question mark: `SELECT p.id AS p__id, p.genre AS p__genre FROM profile p WHERE (p.sf_guard_user_id = ?)`). I don't get this... why concatenation works OK and `?` in DQL no?

Comment: @Ek Kosmos: You should read how prepared statement works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980/how-do-prepared-statements-work find out some more tutorial on this. You will get what I am asking for

Comment: The problem was that the profile for user 11 was not in the database. Because if I check for user 10 is working right (question mark is replaced). However this is strange thing, why if the user not exist the question mark is not replaced ? Doctrine should send some kind of error, but the only thing was that he did not change the question mark...

Comment: The above answer is correct, Doctrine will always use the ? in getSqlQuery(), this is the designed behavior.  If you want to show the parameters that are going to be sent with the query, `print_r($query->getParams());`